# Issue in rendering Swagger OpenAPI v3 UI + Springboot project

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui

I am getting the error -
"**Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).**"
when I paste the generated json from /api-docs to editor.swagger.io.
*I have some observations.*

1. localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/ yields -
   `"{\"openapi\":\"3.0.1\", "\info\":{ ----------------`
   This json gives the mentioned error in editor.swagger.io.
2. On manually removing the initial double quotes and escape character i.e.
   `{"openapi":"3.0.1", "info":{ ----------------` the error goes away i.e. UI is rendered without any issue.
3. My project springboot version is 2.2.13.RELEASE, springdoc-openapi-ui version is 1.5.8, jackson-databind version is 2.10.5.1
4. OpenAPI config class -

```
@Configuration
public class Config1 {
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("user")
            .pathsToMatch("/v1/**")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .info(new Info().title("title1").description("test").version("1.0.0"));
}
```

Please let me know if any further information is required from my end. Any inputs regarding the issue will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your Springdoc configs and any code that could be related to how the `/api-docs/` content is generated & served.

Comment: @Helen I have added Springdoc config as point 4 in the question. As per my understanding /api-docs/ content is generated by default from springdoc-openapi-ui package. Please let me know if you need any further input. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with spring-boot-2.6.4, springdoc-openapi-1.6.6.
The problem is localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/ responses "{"openapi":"3.0.1", "\info":{..." which is a String, NOT a valid JSON as expected.

It turns out in my `WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer`, it doesn't have a `StringHttpMessageConverter`, so the solution is to add it to converters:

```
  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter());
    ...
  }

  @Bean
  public StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter() {
    StringHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.ALL));
    return messageConverter;
  }
```

If you're extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` instead of implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`, probably you'll not get this error as the `StringHttpMessageConverter` is added by default.

Answer (score -3):

You can use  `.version("v0.0.1")` in your `customOpenAPI` or `publicApi` like this

```
@Bean
  public OpenAPI springShopOpenAPI() {
      return new OpenAPI()
              .version("v0.0.1"));
  }
```

For more details see docs https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

Comment: Version is just a label, how could it fix the parsing issue?